# How to include square brackets to the JSON object using SQL query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I am searching for long time for this, how can I add an additional array bracket in the sub select using SQL.

Current data :

```
"improvementType":{"optionID":645,"optionGroupID":87,"optionText":"Readiness","optionGroupName":"ImprovementType"},{"optionID":642,"optionGroupID":87,"optionText":"Policy","optionGroupName":"ImprovementType"}
```

my output should be like this.

```
"improvementType":[{"optionID":645,"optionGroupID":87,"optionText":"Readiness","optionGroupName":"ImprovementType"},{"optionID":642,"optionGroupID":87,"optionText":"Policy","optionGroupName":"ImprovementType"}]
```

How can I query that? Can anyone please help me?

Comment: 1) you need to tag your database 2) provide the code that produces that json string

Comment: @eshirvana I am producing the data from C# code. I just have to update the existing values with Array bracket using SQL query

Comment: then do it in your c# code, its going to be much easier

Comment: its already done in C# now @eshirvana. But I have bulk data which has not having array brackets. I have to update the existing data with '[' .

Comment: I was going to suggest OPNENJSON, however, your data will cause a parse exception because it is not properly formatted. Is that the only shape of the data or does it vary?

Comment: it doesn't very most of the times. But sometimes its child nodes will change @ross

Comment: How are you producing this JSON fragment in C#? Given that it's invalid JSON it seems like it has been constructed manually, such as with StringBuilder, instead of using Newtonsoft.Json or System.Text.Json. Fix the C# code then you won't need to mess with it in SQL Server.